# Prompt for input

Tags: python, user-interface

I need some help making this short program into a GUI. I would like it to prompt for Point A and then move on through the program. I just am confused on how to do this with tkinter. Any help is appreciated

```
import sys

while True:

num_sales=int(input("How many sales were completed? "))  # POINT A

while num_sales < 0:
    print("Error. Number of sales cannot be less than 0.")
    print("")
    num_sales=int(input("How many sales were completed? "))

number = 0
total_sales = 0


while number < num_sales:



    sale = float(input("Sale amount: "))


    while sale < 0:
        print("Error. The sale value cannot be less than 0.")
        print("")
        sale = float(input("Sale amount: "))



    number += 1
    total_sales += sale



print("The total sales are $",total_sales)


if total_sales < 10000:
    commission = (8.2/100)*(total_sales)
    print("Total commission is $",commission)

elif 10000 < total_sales < 25000:
    commission = (17/100)*(total_sales)
    print("Total commission is $",commission)

elif total_sales > 25000:
    commission = (23.25/100)*(total_sales)
    print("Total commission is $",commission)

else:
    print("Unknown Error.")
    sys.exit()

print("")

done = input("Are you finished running commissions? (Y/N) ")

if done == "Y":
    sys.exit()

elif done == "y":
    sys.exit()

print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Turning a python script into a GUI application is not as simple as `GUI(myProgram)`. You're going to need to get into different GUI toolkit's first. In my opinion, the two best for python are [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) (pronounced *tee-kay-inter*) and [PyQt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt).

I'd recommend you start with Tkinter. It comes built into Python and should satisfy your needs for now. PyQt - which you have to download separately - is, in general, more powerful. As Justice Robles mentioned in his answer, there are plenty of tutorials online for learning Tkinter and I would highly recommend [TheNewBoston's](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBwibXFtPtflztSNPGuIB_d) (or Bucky's) tutorials. However, these are just an introduction.

Comment: WxWidgets also deserves a mention and pointer: https://www.wxwidgets.org/  IMO WxWidgets has a much less steep learning curve than PyQt, and may be a better choice for a beginner. PyQt is doubtless more powerful once you have mastered it.

Comment: I've always pronounced it "Teh-kin-ter."